# How to implement multiple selection in listview with LVN_MARQUEEBEGIN

Tags: c++, listview, winapi, multipleselection

I have a listview with multiple selection enabled. The user can get multiple selection by clicking several items while pressing the shift or Ctrl keys. What I try to implement is to get multiple selection by pressing and holding down the mouse left button and dragging over the items to select them.

I tried to respond to LVN_MARQUEEBEGIN as per Microsoft documentation. My program never receive this message. The documentation does not tell how to respond to this message.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
static int  Count ;
static int  SelectedItem ;

case WM_NOTIFY :

  switch ((reinterpret_cast <NMHDR *> (lParam))->code) {

    case NM_CLICK:
        #define pnmitem ((NMITEMACTIVATE *) lParam)
        if (SelectedItem == pnmitem->iItem) {  // item clicked again
            SelectedItem = -1 ;
            ListView_SetItemState (hwndListView,-1,0,0x000F) ;
        } /* if (SelectedItem == pnmitem->iItem) */
        else {
            if (pnmitem->iItem != -1)
                SelectedItem = pnmitem->iItem ;
        } /* else */

        Count = ListView_GetSelectedCount (hwndListView) ;
        switch (Count) {
            case 0 :
                EnableWindow (hwndMerge,false) ;
                EnableWindow (hwndSplit,false) ;
                break ;
            case 1 :
                EnableWindow (hwndMerge,false) ;
                EnableWindow (hwndSplit,true) ;
                break ;
            default :
                EnableWindow (hwndMerge,true) ;
                EnableWindow (hwndSplit,true) ;
        } /* switch (Count) */
        return true ;

    case LVN_MARQUEEBEGIN :
        ;
        ;
        return 0 ;

  } /* switch ((reinterpret_cast <NMHDR *> (lParam))->code) */
  break ;
```

1. Is LVN_MARQUEEBEGIN is the right message to use in my case.
2. It seems to me there should be another message when selection is done. Or why Microsoft called it xxxbegin. But I could not find that other message.
3. Can any one advise me where I can find an example or sample code for the use of LVN_MARQUEEBEGIN.

Thank you all

Comment: Related, if not dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56619044/7571258

Comment: You don't need to do anything special to get the marquee behaviour. No need to handle that notification at all.

Comment: I checked the post mentioned by zett42 and found that my program received LVN_MARQUEEBEGIN message when I started selection outside the items as mentioned in the pucher post.

Comment: I commented the lines handling LVN_MARQUEEBEGIN and found the selection works as Jonathan Potter mentioned. My problem was I adjusted the listview column widths to use the full window space. So there is no place to start selection unless I rearrange the column width. So, I will have to follow the "ugly hack" suggested by Anders in pucher post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CListCtrl select multiple lines with the mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56619044/clistctrl-select-multiple-lines-with-the-mouse)